# Grep that works with overlapping patterns

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression

I want to count the number of repeating patterns `aa` in a very big file. So I use the following command:

```
grep -o "aa" ./bwt/dblp.txt | wc -l
```

This works, except when I have a string such as `aaa`, which then matches this as only 1 pattern. In my use case, I need that the first 2 `a`s mean one pattern, but the last 2 `a`s are a second patter (this means that the middle `a` from `aaa` can be reused).

How can I achieve this?

Please note the file is very big so an "optimised" way, if possible, would be better. Anyhow, any working solution is obviously welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need perl regular expressions for this. With a `grep` that supports the `-P` flag:

```
grep -oP '(?<=a)a' file | wc -l
```

This is a positive [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It matches a single `a` which is preceded by another `a`.

---

If you prefer `perl` (or your `grep` doesn't support the `-P` flag):

```
perl -ne 'while(m/(?<=a)a/g){$a++}END{print "$a\n"}' file
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
aa
aaa
aaaa
```

The first line should be 1 match, the second one two, and the third one tree; all together 6:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=a)a' file | wc -l
6
```

Comment: Somehow I get an error message:grep -oP '(?<=a)a' ./bwt/dblp.txt | wc -l
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
       0

Comment: @testTester See my edited answer, I added a perl solution

Comment: Thanks! I just realized this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches. Thanks a lot for this. Is there a more "general" way of achieving this? E.g.: I also need to search for "aka" in a string such as "akaka". How would this look like? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @testTester that's a different question

Comment: @roaima - apologies, I didn't realise these would be different cases until now.

Comment: I think just: `perl -ne '$a++ while(m/(?<=a)ka/g); END{print "$a\n"}' file`, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can count repeated pairs of letters such as your example `aa` in a data file `big_file` like this:

```
tr -cs a '\012' <big_file | awk '/aa/{n += length - 1}; END {print n+0}'
```

The line can be explained like this

- The `tr` changes any sequence of characters that is not `a` into a newline. This splits multiple occurrences of `aa...` onto separate lines
- The `awk` counts the length of non-zero lines. By using the property that a sequence of N characters contains N-1 overlapping pairs, it can sum up the number of overlapping pairs and produce a total at the end of the file

---

Actually, since the file is "very large" you will get a better response by including a `grep` in the pipeline like this:

```
tr -cs a '\012' <big_file | grep aa | awk '{n += length - 1}; END {print n+0}'
```

Comment: Add the `-s` option to `tr`. `grep aa` would be more efficient than `grep .`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'd assumed (without testing - until now) that this would squeeze my sequences of `a...a`. I'm intrigued to see it honours the `-c` flag. Thank you

Comment: Or just `tr -cs a '\n' < file | sed -n 's/^aa//p' | wc -c`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas at this point I think TTMOWTDI strikes.

Comment: to understand @StéphaneChazelas comment: changes non-a to newlines, then sed : doesn't print anything by default, and when it sees '^aa' it replaces 'aa' with nothing and then it (p)rints what remains on that line (= any remaining 'a' on that line, without the first aa pair) : wc -c counts then everything (newlines and any remaining a). (iow, the first aa is counted as a newline!).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, chaos' answer outputs nothing on my system (Debian 11.5, GNU grep 3.6). Here's what works for me, just in case it might be useful to someone else:

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 '(\w)(?=(\w))' file
```

This is similar in spirit to what has been proposed: match the first letter using capture group 1 if it is followed by another letter in capture group 2, only the latter is matched using a positive lookahead so we can still consume it afterwards. And then, display both groups using `-o1` and `-o2`.

This generalises straightforwardly to subsequences of length `n`:

```
pcregrep -o1 -o2 '(\w)(?=(\w{n-1}))' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do the matching of the regexp inside a look ahead operator so the matching will be attempted at every byte position and can be used with arbitrary regexps:

```
$ echo aaaa | perl -ne '$n += () = /(?=aa)/g; END{printf "%d\n", $n}'
3
```

```
$ echo ababa | perl -ne '$n += () = /(?=aba)/g; END{printf "%d\n", $n}'
2
```

Answer (score -3):

```
grep -ow aa ./bwt/dblp.txt | wc -l
```